# Can I create aliases with make?

Tags: bash, make, bash-alias

Is it possible for `make` to create aliases?

Here's what I tried:

**Makefile**

```
aliases:
  alias hello='echo world'
  alias holy='echo cow'
```

It doesn't work as-is, presumably because the alias command runs outside the context of the shell. Is it possible to execute them in-context? Or "export" the created aliases somehow?

If not, what's the best alternative to bringing aliases to a host in bulk? (As add-ons in a repo, for example.)

Comment: The best you can do is add them to `~/.bash_aliases` and they will be loaded the next time `bash` is restarted. If you don't want to restart, you can type `. ~/.bash_aliases` to import manually.

Comment: Do you want run `hello` command to `echo world`? Or why do you need it?

Comment: @uzsolt As a silly example, yes. In my current use-case, leaning towards just copying small shell scripts to `/usr/local/bin` or something -- None of my aliases, thus far, do anything more than proxy for other commands and scripts.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't.
More information in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939213/makefile-to-add-aliases